# Bash one liner to change configuration parameters

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a config file with following structure.

```
ValueOne = 1
ValueTwo = 2
ValueThree = 3
```

I want a one liner bash script to find ValueTwo and change the value to 22222.

Any idea? 
*Not School Thing*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I bet there'll be better ones but here's my go:

If the config file has parameters on their own line

```
sed -i '/ValueTwo/s/= .*/= 22222/' config_file
```

- `/ValueTwo/` : Search for the string `ValueTwo` to find which line to operate on ([Addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview-1))
- `s/= .*/= 22222/` : On the lines that match the search above, substitute `= .*` for `= 22222` ([Substitute](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-s-Command))
- `= .*` : Search for the `=` character followed by a space () character followed by 0 or more of any character (`.*`) ([Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/0YaHl8/1))
- `= 22222` : Replace what's found with the literal string `= 22222`

This will replace the contents of config_file in-place.  To create a new file with the parameter changed, remove `-i` and place `> new_file` at the end of the line.

---

If your config file has parameters on the same line (like the unedited question):

```
sed -i 's/ValueTwo = [^ ]*/ValueTwo = 22222/' config_file
```

This will replace the contents of config_file in-place as well.  It will work as long as there are no spaces in the parameter for ValueTwo.  This will also work in the case where parameters are on their own line, but the former method is perhaps more robust in that case.

Comment: I think you lost your bet.

Comment: That is some RegEx'ish mumbo jumbo, would love an explanation `/s/=`?

Comment: @RayFoss I made an edit to the answer to add an explanation of the Regex with links to the docs

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/ValueTwo = 2/ValueTwo = 22222/' path/to/configfile
```

will edit the file in-place and save a copy of the original in case of finger trouble. You can do the same with awk.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for `awk`:

```
awk '/ValueTwo/{$3=22222}1;' file > newfile
```

The above checks whether a given line matches ValueTwo and sets the 3d field to `222` on matching lines. The `1;` is just an awk shgorthand way of writing `print $0`, it will print each line. Since it is outside the match block (`/ValueTwo/{}`), it will cause all lines to be printed.

Since you asked for a bash solution though (don't know why you would prefer one but still), you could try this:

```
while read key eq val; do
    [ $key = "ValueTwo" ] && val=22222
    printf "%s %s %s\n" $key $eq $val
done <  file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ValueTwo` is a number, `sed` will do just fine:

```
sed -e 's/ValueTwo = [0-9]*/ValueTwo = 2222/g' your_config_file > output_file
```

Comment: +1 but why would you limit it to numbers? What's wrong with `.*`?

Comment: @terdon, in the first version of the question all variables were in one line, separated by whitespaces.

Also it is a good practice to limit the scope of regular expression to values that you expect to find - this way you can filter out some unexpected errors - e.g. when a text is logged instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ex` editor (part of Vi):

```
ex +'%s/^ValueTwo[^=]\?=[^0-9]\?\zs[^$]\+/22222/' -scwq config.ini
```

Explanation:

- `+cmd` - executes ex/vi **c**ommand;
- `%s/foo/bar/` - **s**earch and replace syntax;
- `^` - beginning of the line;
- `[^=]\?=[^0-9]\?` - selects area around equal character (`=`);
- `\zs[^$]` - selects part for the replacement till end of the line;
- `/22222/` - pattern to replace to (everything after `\zs`);
- `-s` - **s**ilent mode;
- `-c<command>` - executes `<command>`;
- `-cwq` - executes **w**rite and **q**uit;